# Command to delete substring in "note" field of bibtex *.bst

Tags: bibtex, xstring, bibliographystyle

I have a CV where all my presentations are formatted using "@misc" -- for some of the publications I would like to note them as "invited," and I have a version of my CV where I have done so by appending it to the location (by cheating with the ISSN field)

```
@misc{mypresentation2011,
title= {How do I do this with LaTeX?},
author = {Jane Q. Smith},
month = {November},
year = {2011},
howpublished={talk},
issn={Seattle, WA, USA, Invited},
note={University of Washington Department of Mathematics Seminar Series}
}
```

For another CV (biosketch) with a second *.bst file, I'd like to just have a separate section for invited talks. In this case, tacking on ", Invited" is redundant and I'd like to do a search and replace it with an empty string. This way I need one .bib file and one CV keeps the string as written and the other one nukes it.

The below macro with xstring does what I want it to do with an entry in the main .tex file but I cannot get it to behave well in the *bst file or wrapped around the \bibentry that I use...

```
\newcommand{\delinvited}[1]{%
  \StrDel{\bibentry{#1}}{, Invited}
}
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I did eventually figureout a workaround. Not sure if it's the most elegant but I'll post here for future stumblers.

Based on the most excellent [TameTheBeast](https://ctan.org/pkg/tamethebeast/), I added these two functions to my bst file (note they need to be added *under* the "not" function definition, if you don't have one, you must add one, also following TtB)

```
%% from Tame the Beast
INTEGERS{ l }
FUNCTION{ string.length }
{
  #1 'l :=
  {duplicate$ duplicate$ #1 l substring$ = not}
    {l #1 + 'l :=}
  while$
  pop$ l
}

STRINGS{replace find text}
INTEGERS{find_length}
FUNCTION{find.replace}
{ 'replace :=
  'find :=
  'text :=
  find string.length 'find_length :=
  ""
    { text empty$ not }
    { text #1 find_length substring$ find =
        {
          replace *
          text #1 find_length + global.max$ substring$ 'text :=
        }
        { text #1 #1 substring$ *
          text #2 global.max$ substring$ 'text :=
        }
      if$
    }
  while$
}
```

Then, I added a function that strips ", Invited" from the last string on the stack when formatting ISSN (i.e., my fake conference information)

```
% Here we use ISSN as location + invited status
% Remove ", Invited" from strings
FUNCTION {removeinvite.issn}
{
  ", Invited" "" find.replace
}

FUNCTION {format.issn}
{ issn empty$
    { "" }
    { "" * issn removeinvite.issn }
  if$
}
```

and this gives the desired behavior (assuming I denoted invited presentations as "Location, Invited" in my ISSN field).